# unable to connect oracle db instance from sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>
> ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

I dont have admin privileges to elevate my access level. we are sharing common credentials to access the database instance

Answer (score 1):

It says that database is shut down. Contact your DBA and ask them to start it up.

Comment: other team members can connect this instance

Comment: When Oracle (database) is not available, then it is not available to any of you. Are you **sure** you're connecting to the right database?

Comment: "other team members can connect this instance". Then you are not connecting to the database that you think you are.  What is your client program ... sqlplus?  SQL Dev?  Compare your connection definition/string to that of those who can connect.  Compare your tnsnames.ora to theirs.

Comment: Issue is with database name. It is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to connect via `sqlplus` - try performing a `sudo su - oracle` first (or whichever user was used to install Oracle - perhaps the one that owns `/opt/oracle`).